# How do I store elements in a list in ascending order that come from two other list C#?

Tags: c#

The problem I am having is displaying items from my list in ascending order. I understand the problem that is creating this issue which is I am adding caccounts to the List and then adding saccounts to the list but i am not sure of any other way I can do this. The outcome should be to display the accounts in whatever order they were created which is dependent on the user. So as you see by the image below it is storing and displaying all created checking accounts first then savings accounts which is incorrect. It should show the in the order they were created. As you see from the image below the items are out of order. It should show Savings account 1 first then Checking account 2 and so on.

[image: This is how the items are being displayed]

This is the code that is adding the items to this list and is creating the problem

```
List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

accounts.AddRange(caccounts);
accounts.AddRange(saccounts);

foreach (Account account in accounts)
{
    List<Transaction> transactions = account.closeMonth();

    allTransactions.AddRange(transactions);
}
```

This code shows the list I am adding saccounts and caccounts to

```
List<SavingsAccount> saccounts = new List<SavingsAccount>();
List<CheckingAccount> caccounts = new List<CheckingAccount>();
List<Transaction> allTransactions = new List<Transaction>();
```

This is code that I have in my checking class and savings class that override close month in the abstract account class

```
public override List<Transaction> closeMonth()
{
    var transactions = new List<Transaction>();

    var endString = new Transaction();

    string reportString = ("Checking account: " + AccountID.ToString() + 
        " has a balance of $" + endingBalance.ToString());

    endString.EndOfMonth = reportString;
    transactions.Add(endString);

    return transactions;
}
```

This is the property for the AccountID and i have this in the checking and savings class

```
class SavingsAccount : Account
{
    public override int AccountID { get; set; }
}
```

When the account is originally created this is the code that assigns the AccountID

```
if (checkingRadioButton1.Checked == true)
{
    _nextIndex++;
    transactionLabel5.Text = "Checking Account: #" + _nextIndex + 
        " created with a starting balance of $" + balance;
    accountTextBox1.Text = "" + _nextIndex;
    caccounts.Add(new CheckingAccount(balance)
    {
        AccountID = _nextIndex,
        Student = isStudent
    });
}
else if (savingsRadioButton2.Checked == true)
{
    _nextIndex++;
    transactionLabel5.Text = "Savings Account: #" + _nextIndex + 
        "   created with a starting balance of $" + balance;
    accountTextBox1.Text = "" + _nextIndex;
    saccounts.Add(new SavingsAccount(balance)
    {
        AccountID = _nextIndex,
        Senior = isSenior
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you have to store an ID that is unique over both lists or a creation date or something like this. Then you can union both lists and then do an `order by`

Comment: @Josef Biehler I have never used a union or order by but I will google it and see what that does. If you have the time can you provide a sample code of what you are talking about?

Comment: FYI, your `closeMonth()` method can be reduced to one line: `return new List<Transaction> {new Transaction {EndOfMonth = $"Checking account: {AccountID} has a balance of ${endingBalance}"}};`

Comment: Why do you override `AccountID` (i.e. why is `Account` abstract)? Why not just use the base class? For that matter, how are the `CheckingAccount` and `SavingsAccount` class different from each other, or from the `Account` base class? It feels like this code is unnecessarily complicated, but maybe I'm not seeing the big picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `OrderBy` on the collection.

```
var orderedTransactions = allTransactions.OrderBy(x=>x.AccountId).ToList();
```

Of course you would need to have that CreateDate or whatever property you want ordered by in your object.

Comment: I have a property for AccountId so are you stating i can do an Order By using it?

Comment: Yes you can order by any property and the collection will be ordered accordingly. Just change .OrderBy(x=>x.AccountId).ToList(); Use .OrderByDesc(x=> x.AccountId) if you need in desc order.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using this code to merge accounts into one list

```
 List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

        accounts.AddRange(caccounts);
        accounts.AddRange(saccounts);

        foreach (Account account in accounts)
        {
            List<Transaction> transactions = account.closeMonth();

            allTransactions.AddRange(transactions);
        }
```

you can use this code

```
List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
            int saccountsAdded = 0;
            int caccountsAdded = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < saccounts.Count + caccounts.Count; i++)
            {
                if(saccountsAdded == saccounts.Count)
                {
                    accounts[i] = caccounts[caccountsAdded++];
                    continue;
                }
                if (caccountsAdded == caccounts.Count)
                {
                    accounts[i] = saccounts[saccountsAdded++];
                    continue;
                }
                if (saccounts[saccountsAdded].AccountID > caccounts[caccountsAdded].AccountID)
                {
                    accounts[i] = caccounts[caccountsAdded ++];

                }
                else
                {
                    accounts[i] = saccounts[saccountsAdded ++];

                }
            }
```

In my case, you are sorting accounts when you are combining them and then your accounts list will be ordered. 
You can also use the solution from NoSaidTheCompiler, the only difference is that I am sorting and populating the list at the same time and he firstly populates the list and sorts after the list has been populated

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can order your `Transactions` by the `AccountID` using the `System.Linq` extension method `OrderBy` (along with a `.SelectMany` method call to flatten each account's transaction list) before you output them:

```
List<Transaction> transactions = accounts
    .OrderBy(a => a.AccountID)
    .SelectMany(a => a.closeMonth())
    .ToList();
```

---

**Other thoughts**

As I was answering your question, I couldn't figure out why `Account` was abstract, or why there was a separate class for `CheckingAccount` and `SavingsAccount`, because I couldn't see a difference between the two and it felt so redundant to override all these abstract properties and methods with the exact same code in two different classes.

With that in mind, I felt compelled to share some thoughts which may or may not apply to your specific situation. Note that I have never written a banking app before, so there are probably many things I'm not thinkning of - just wanted to share this in case it helps.

**Accounts**

To me, an account is an account. There may be different rules associated with one type or another, but those can be defined by the `Bank` that creates the accounts, and the class could have a `List<Rule> AccountRules` that would be set based on that particular bank's policies (i.e. perhaps there is a minimum balance for a Checking account, but not a Savings account, or they have different interest rate schedules, or something else, but nothing that I can think of that is inherently different).

But in the end, an account is a repository for a decimal amount which can be changed by a `Withdrawl` or a `Deposit` (or an `Interest` accruement).

**Transactions**

Also, the `closeMonth()` method seemed really strange to me. It returns a `List<Transaction>` that contains a single item. Instead, I think an `Account` should have a `List<Transaction>` that gets populated from *every* public method - even balance inquiries. Then this list can be queried to get the activities within a particular time frame, such as a month or a year (by filtering on the `Transaction.Timestamp` property). Or it could be queried to get different types of transactions (by filtering on the `Transaction.TransactionType` property).

To simplify adding a new transaction to the list, I added a `private AddTransaction` method that takes in a `Transaction.Type` and a description of the transaction. It then creates the `Transaction` and adds it to the list. Also notice that the `Transaction` class automatically adds the current `DateTime` as a `Timestamp`, so there's no need to worry about that on the client side.

**Code**

To prevent race conditions where `Deposit` and `Withdrawl` are called at the same time from different threads, I added some `lock()` blocks around any code that accessed `Balance`.

I also added an override to the `ToString` method on the `Transaction` class so that it was easier to output the details of each transaction.

Another item of interest is that you can format a `decimal` as currency by using the `C` format string (i.e. if you have `decimal balance = 5M;` you can do `balance.ToString("C")` or `"{balance:C}"` and the string result will be `"$5.00"` in the U.S. or `"£5.00"` in England).

So the classes might then look something like the following:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public enum Type { Open, Close, Deposit, Withdrawl, Inquiry, Other }
    public Type TransactionType { get; }
    public string Description { get; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; }

    public Transaction(Type transactionType, string description)
    {
        TransactionType = transactionType;
        Description = description;
        Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Timestamp}: {TransactionType} - {Description}";
    }
}

public class Account
{
    public enum Type { Checking, Savings }
    public Type AccountType { get; }
    public int Id { get; }
    public List<Transaction> Transactions { get; private set; }

    private static readonly object IdLock = new object();
    private static int _lastAccountId;

    private readonly object balanceLock = new object();
    private decimal balance;

    public Account(decimal initialDeposit, Type accountType)
    {
        if (initialDeposit < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("initialDeposit cannot be negative");
        }

        AccountType = accountType;
        balance = initialDeposit;

        lock (IdLock)
        {
            Id = ++_lastAccountId;
        }

        AddTransaction(Transaction.Type.Open, 
            $"{AccountType} account Id {Id} created with a deposit of: {balance:C}.");
    }

    public void Deposit(decimal amount)
    {
        if (amount < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Deposit amount cannot be negative");
        }

        lock (balanceLock)
        {
            balance += amount;
            AddTransaction(Transaction.Type.Deposit,
                $"{amount} was deposited. New balance: {balance:C}.");
        }
    }

    public void Withdraw(decimal amount)
    {
        if (amount < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Withdrawl amount cannot be negative");
        }

        if (amount > balance)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                "Cannot withdraw more money than the account contains");
        }

        lock (balanceLock)
        {
            balance -= amount;
            AddTransaction(Transaction.Type.Withdrawl,
                $"{amount} was withdrawn. New balance: {balance:C}.");
        }
    }

    public decimal GetBalance()
    {
        lock (balanceLock)
        {
            AddTransaction(Transaction.Type.Inquiry,
                $"Balance inquiry made. Balance: {balance:C}.");
            return balance;
        }
    }

    private void AddTransaction(Transaction.Type transactionType, string description)
    {
        if (Transactions == null) Transactions = new List<Transaction>();
        Transactions.Add(new Transaction(transactionType, description));
    }
}
```

So, with all that, here's an example that populates a list of accounts in the same order that you have shown in your form above, with an example of how you can output all the transactions for the accounts ordered by the account id:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Adding accounts in the same order as they appear on your form
    var accounts = new List<Account>
    {
        new Account(293.05M, Account.Type.Checking),
        new Account(293.05M, Account.Type.Checking),
        new Account(300M, Account.Type.Savings),
        new Account(300M, Account.Type.Savings),
    };

    // Sort transactions by account Id
    List<Transaction> transactions = accounts
            .OrderBy(a => a.Id)
            .SelectMany(a => a.Transactions)
            .ToList();

    // Write results to Console
    transactions.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you and this information you provided was very insightful. To answer your question I have it setup with and abstract account class and a checking and savings class to override it because this is an assignment which requires me to have it designed exactly as such. The information you have provided is very helpful and I thank you for it.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. :)